# How does Java know where to jump to when breaking out of a loop?

Tags: java, loops, compilation

```
while (condition) {

    if (condition) {
        statement1;
        statement2;

        break;
    } else {
        statement3;
        statement4;
    }

}
```

By using `break` in the if clause, we ensure the loop is halted and exited.

I don't understand how the break statement "knows" that it is within a loop for it to exit out of in the first place, or how it "knows" where to jump to.  How does this happen?

Comment: The compiler knows where the loop is.

Comment: @HotLicks The compiler should be omniscient :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I don't understand how the break statement "knows" that it is within a loop for it to exit out of in the first place.

The `break` statement does not know that it's within a `switch` or loop statement. The compiler *verifies* that the `break` statement is within a `switch` or loop statement. If it encounters a `break` statement that is *not* within a loop statement, it will emit a compile-time error.

> If no `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement in the immediately enclosing method, constructor, or initializer contains the break statement, a compile-time error occurs.

If the compiler is able to verify that the `break` statement is within a `switch` or loop statement, it will then emit JVM instructions to jump abruptly to the first statement immediately after the nearest enclosing loop.

Thus:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
         break;
    }
}
```

would be translated by the compiler into:

```
0:  iconst_0        # push integer 0 onto stack
1:  istore_1        # store top of stack in local 1 as integer                  
                    # i = 0
2:  iload_1         # push integer in local 1 onto stack
3:  bipush 10       # push integer 10 onto stack
5:  if_icmpge 23    # pop and compare top two (as integers), jump if first >= second
                    # if i >= 10, end for
8:  iload_1         # push integer in local 1 onto stack
9:  iconst_2        # push integer 2 onto stack
10: irem            # pop top two and computes first % second and pushes result
                    # i % 2
11: ifne 17         # pop top (as integer) and jump if not zero to 17
                    # if(i % 2 == 0) 
14: goto 23         # this is the break statement
17: iinc 1, 1       # increment local 1 by 1
                    # i++
20: goto 2          # go to top of loop
                    # loop
23: return          # end of loop body
```

Comment: What do you use to generate the compiler code. This will definitely help a lot to understand some concepts.

Comment: With `Foo.class` in your classpath, `javap -c Foo` will output the bytecode.

Comment: @JNL: You'll have to forgive me, I swapped a `p` and `c` in the previous comment. I've edited to correct!

Comment: +1 for low-level code, So if I have `myc.calss` then `javap -c myc.calss` will output this code ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes if you name the file with the correct extension.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: Leave off the `.class`. Just `javap -c nameofclass`. If you have `myc.class` in the current directory just say `javap -c myc`.

Comment: @Jason Yes got it, I also read a short doc: [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 20):

`break` isn't your standard function. It's a keyword that's used by the Java compiler. When it sees it, it'll insert a bytecode instruction to jump to directly outside the loop, after it. This is a simple goto bytecode as shown in the answer given by Jason.

Likewise, the `continue` keyword effectively jumps to the beginning of the loop<sup>1</sup>.

`return` does this out of a function block, though with a few differences as it may need to carry a value or a reference pointing to the heap.

---

<sup>1 - It is actually a bit more complicated than this.  Probably the best simple but accurate "model" that works for all Java loops is that `continue` is equivalent to jumping to an imaginary *empty* statement at the end of the loop body.</sup>

Comment: The stack cannot be 'cleaned up'. There is no bytecode instruction that corresponds to the closing }.

Answer (score 17):

> I don't understand how the break statement "knows" that it is within a loop for it to exit out of in the first place.

The compiler turns your program into a parse tree. Everything in the parse tree has a parent, except the root. The break statement must have a parent loop somewhere up the tree (or, of course, a parent switch statement).

Comment: EJP -- This an excellent line `The break statement must have a parent loop` simply shows how break implemented. a very concise and nice answer!

Comment: This is the most direct answer to the question. I like the detail of the byte-code answers, but the tree the compiler builds from the code is how it knows to generate that byte-code.

Answer (score 4):

If you have ever taken a look at assembly or Java byte code, this will make more sense.  At a lower level, your program is compiled into "byte code" that takes advantage of registers, addresses, etc.  A simple if statement can be translated into something like:

```
3: if_icmpeq 5
4: goto 10
5: iconst_1
6: iload_1
7: iconst_2
8: iload_2
9: if_icmpeq 10
10: // end of if-else statement
```

This might be (really bad) bytecode for:

```
if ( x == y )
  if ( 1 == 2 )
```

Essentially, at a lower level, you use labels/line numbers and gotos to jump around the code.  So a `break` essentially means, goto the last line of the if statement or loop.

Answer (score 4):

The break statement has two forms: **labeled and unlabeled**.

You can use an **unlabeled break** to terminate a `for, while, or do-while loop.`

An **unlabeled break statement** terminates the `innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement`, but a `labeled break terminates an outer statement`.

```
   search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                 j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == 5) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is valid in explaining what a break does, but not how it does it at a low level, as the OP asks.

Comment: @hexafraction True. I answered the question yesterday and the question was edited later. I just wanted to bring into light label and unlabeled break statement too, since we had so many answers, but none had mentioned it. This would definitely help someone who is new to programming